# Silverlight Datagrid: Changing cell styles, based on values

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, cells

I have some data. I want to go through that data and change cells (for example - Background color), if that data meets a certain condition. Somehow, I've not been able to figure it out how to do this seemingly easy thing in Silverlight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is slightly old code (from before RTM), but does something like what you're looking for. It checks some data on an object in a row and then sets the colour of the row accordingly.

**XAML:**

```
<my:DataGrid x:Name="Grid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" GridlinesVisibility="None" PreparingRow="Grid_PreparingRow">
    <my:DataGrid.Columns>
        <my:DataGridTextBoxColumn 
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Cheese}" 
            Header="Cheese"></my:DataGridTextBoxColumn>
        <my:DataGridTextBoxColumn 
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Biscuit}" 
            Header="Biscuit"></my:DataGridTextBoxColumn>
    </my:DataGrid.Columns>
</my:DataGrid>
```

**Code:**

```
this.Grid.AlternatingRowBackground = null; 

private void Grid_PreparingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    CheesyClass c = e.Row.DataContext as CheesyClass;
    if (c != null && c.Cheese == "cheddar")
    {
       e.Row.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 125, 125));
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems like it makes sense over a valueconvertor for changing the color of the entire row. is that right?

Comment: Note: LoadingRow is the new name for PreparingRow

Answer (score 1):

Actually this won't work in all examples. See these links for the 'proper' way of achieving this

http://silverlight.net/forums/p/27465/93474.aspx#93474

http://silverlight.net/forums/t/27467.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've generally written custom ValueConverters for each data type being bound that return Visibility, Colour, etc.

This gives a single point where the customisation rules are defined and I've found works very well.

Robin's second link describes writing a custom ValueConverter.